# SignalR not Invoking client Side function using IE but working on Chrome

Tags: internet-explorer, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I am troubled by SignalR client side method not working on IE. It works fine with chrome but when i use ie 10 it doesn't invoke my client side function here is my code

controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> _Export( string columns)
    {
        var vmexport = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<VMEXPORT[]>(columns);
        var filePath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/") + "CSV\\" + AgentPrompttx + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyyHHmm") + ".csv";

        var replycls = await Task.Run(() => _serviceAgent.CreateCsv(arrparam));
        SendNotification(CurrentMember.user_nm);
        return File(filePath, "application/octet-stream", Prompttx + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyyHHmm") + ".csv");
   }
```

Method sending to client:

```
public void SendNotification(string message)
    {
        GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>().Clients.All.receiveNotification(CurrentMember.user_nm);
    }
```

Client Side:

```
$(window).load(function () {

    var myHubConnection = $.connection.myHub;
    myHubConnection.client.setOnline = function (usernm) {
        if ($('#user_kgrid').data('kendoGrid') != undefined)
            $('#user_kgrid').data('kendoGrid').tbody.find('td:contains("' + usernm + '")').eq(0).parent('tr').find('td:contains("Offline")').html('<span><i class="icon-ok-sign"></i></span> Online')
    };

    myHubConnection.client.receiveNotification = function (recipient) {
        if (recipient == $('#usernm').text()) {
            $.growl({
                title: '<strong>SAVING:</strong> ',
                message: '<a href=\"https://twitter.com/Mouse0270\" target=\"_self\">Link Here</a>'
            }, {
                type: 'info',
                placement: {
                    from: "top",
                    align: "right"
                },
            });
        }
        else
            return false;
    };

    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                $.connection.myHub.server.brodcastLogIn($('#usernm').text());
            });
        }, 1000);      
    });
});
```

it is working fine on chrome but not on IE can you please tell me what is wrong with my codes or is there something i need to change??

Comment: Are you certain that your hub successfully starts in IE?  In addition, why are you starting the hub connection twice?

Comment: yes. The hub starts. but the problem that i figured out is the transport type. i  Changed it to long polling and it works on both browser..